# NLog: console app - stop sending repeated emails on repeating failure

Tags: asp.net, console-application, nlog

So, I have console apps galore running as scheduled tasks on various client's servers. These apps occasionally run into network problems and other road blocks. I currently have NLog happily sending alerts via email and logging to our .NET Core API/website.

Thing is, sometimes an app is scheduled to run every 2 minutes (don't ask, no choice) and if that app is having a network error, it will continue to send error emails every 2 minutes until the problem is resolved. While some may appreciate it's tenacity, we do not need all those emails. Just the initial one and maybe one every hour after that for a 'nudge' or reminder.

I have thought about this and have a plan, but I feel like I might be missing some feature of NLog that I could leverage here.

I know about the [Buffering Wrapper](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/BufferingWrapper-target) but that seems to be for a constantly running app. Our console apps run and stop at intervals so this doesn't seem to be the solution.

I could write a 'spooler' app that watches an NLog DB table/file and sends emails based on pertinent conditions like, "Has this error shown within the past X minutes or is it brand new?" and decide to send an email or not... but that seems like extra 'monkey motion' whereas some tweaking of that Buffering Wrapper might work in some way I am not aware of... or some other magical NLog plugin is the key...

Ideas welcome. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

> Thing is, sometimes an app is scheduled to run every 2 minutes (don't ask, no choice) and if that app is having a network error, it will continue to send error emails every 2 minutes until the problem is resolved. While some may appreciate it's tenacity, we do not need all those emails. Just the initial one and maybe one every hour after that for a 'nudge' or reminder.

This is indeed a valid use case. As you have mentioned you could the BufferingWrapper for it, but it's limited, as the messages will be delayed.. In NLog 4.4 the `LimitingWrapper` (see [pull request](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/1514)) is plannend, which limits the amount of messages in a time span.

> I know about the Buffering Wrapper but that seems to be for a constantly running app. Our console apps run and stop at intervals so this doesn't seem to be the solution

This will also count for the upcoming `LimitingWrapper`. We need to store some information (e.g. message already sent), and this is now in process. If you need to save it out-of-process, there will be a lot of choices to be made (where and which format - e.g. file, database, register). I'm not sure if there would be a way to would work for everyone.

Luckily you could easy write your own `Wrapper` with your own custom logic:

Wrapper:

```cs
[Target("MyWrapper", IsWrapper = true)]
public class MyTargetWrapper : WrapperTargetBase
{
     /// <summary>
    /// Option that could be set from XML config.
    /// </summary>
    public int MinutesCount { get; set; }

    protected override void Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
    {

        if (ShouldLog(logEvent)) 
        {
            this.WrappedTarget.WriteAsyncLogEvent(logEvent);

        }

    }

    private bool ShouldLog(logEvent)
    {
       // ----- todo ------
       // e.g. write to file/database when the last error was and check it here.

    }
}
```

Register (as soon as possible, `main()`, `app_start` etc)

```
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.Targets
                        .RegisterDefinition("NameInConfig", typeof(MyNamespace.MyTargetWrapper));
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Writing my own wrapper doesn't seem to make sense since these console apps run via task scheduler every 2 minutes and quit. They run and quit so how do I determine between runs if it caught that error previously using the Buffering Wrapper? (if possible)

Comment: Well you need to store (and read) somewhere that the event was raised (eg. file, database). You could do that in the wrapper.

Comment: right ok, so that's kinda like I said in the question, same concept

Comment: Well this isn't a spooler app? Just extend NLog, no need for an external application.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thing is, we have a lot of clients per server, and it makes more sense to write a single custom spooler and leave NLog as-is instead of customizing it in every site... but thanks for the input, appreciated.